# systemJS "unexpected token error" when importing 3rd party library

Tags: angular, systemjs

I am trying to use [angular2-datatable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable) in an angular2 application
but I am getting the following error when trying to run the application after putting in the imports in the AppModule

```
Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <
```

here is the AppModule

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
 import { AppComponent } from './app.component'
 import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
 import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
 import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
 import { SelectModule } from 'angular2-select';
 import { AppRoutes } from './app.routes';
 import { DataTableModule } from "angular2-datatable";


@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent
],
providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
HttpModule,
FormsModule,
SelectModule,
DataTableModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes)],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and here is my systemjs.config

```
(function (global) {
System.config({
    paths: {
        // paths serve as alias
        'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
        // our app is within the app folder
        app: 'app',
        // angular bundles
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
        // other libraries
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
        'angular2-select': 'node_modules/angular2-select',
        'angular2-datatable': 'node_modules/angular2-datatable'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
        app: {
            main: './main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'angular2-select': {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'angular2-datatable': {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
})(this);
```

I have imported other libraries this same way so I am not sure what I am missing.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to makes sure `lodash` is also referenced in you system js. try adding this...

```
'angular2-select': 'node_modules/angular2-select',
'angular2-datatable': 'node_modules/angular2-datatable',
'lodash': 'npm:lodash/lodash'           <----------------HERE
```

or

```
'lodash': 'node_modules/lodash'
```

Here is my plunker with it being imported correctly 
https://plnkr.co/edit/Yv7gO1eYYNIIOsoDdQrt?p=preview

Comment: I still have the same issue. Where did you see the missing lodash reference?

Comment: This totally worked. I needed to modify the path however. I saw in the angular2-datatables folder was another node_modules folder in which was the lodash folder. I linked to that path and it worked. Than you so much!

Comment: sry had to edit, you don't need the .js at the end. If that doesnt fix your issue then you have an issue somewhere else. have you looked in your node_modules to make sure you actually have angular2-datatable and lodash installed?

Comment: I updated the comment. Thanks a ton! lodash was not installed in my nodemodules but was included with the angular2-datatable package in another node_modules folder.